# Host IP is not visible by LXC guests. Open vSwitch bridge

Tags: networking, lxc, openvswitch

In such way I have configured OVS bridge for LXC containers [LXC with Open vSwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021070/lxc-with-open-vswitch)

It is bridge configuration:

```
# ovs-vsctl show
1b236728-4637-42a5-8b81-53d4c93a6803
    Bridge "switch0"
        Port vethNSCEGY
            Interface vethNSCEGY
        Port "switch0"
            Interface "switch0"
                type: internal
        Port "vethD6TFEB"
            Interface "vethD6TFEB"
    ovs_version: "2.3.2"
```

**switch0** is interface on host and has IP **192.168.100.1/24**
**vethNSCEGY** and **vethD6TFEB** are interfaces for LXC guests.

Eventually first LXC guest with IP **192.168.100.10/24** can ping second LXC guest **192.168.100.11/24** but cant ping host IP **192.168.100.1/24**

Is it OK for OVS? Or do I need smth to enable?

**PS.** IPs on my interfaces:

```
# ip a
...
4: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 52:9d:e1:60:1d:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: switch0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 16:63:eb:47:13:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 scope global switch0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
35: vethNSCEGY: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:d1:06:81:69:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fcd1:6ff:fe81:69ed/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
37: vethD6TFEB: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:ca:e9:16:dd:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fcca:e9ff:fe16:dd81/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft foreve
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad again. `switch0` was down. So turning up of interface helped me:

```
# ip link set dev switch0 up
```